# How to display custom Form/Pre chat form before transferring to an Agent in Einstein Bots

Tags: einstein, pre-chat, snap-ins

I'm using Einstein Bots for knowledge Articles, where in I have a Dialog to transfer to an agent based on some predefined options that the customer has chosen. Everything works, but I would like to show a form with FirstName,LastName, Email and a couple of custom fields from case, before transferring to an agent.

I need to hide the pre chat form at the very beginning of the bot initialization, and show only at the point, when the bot is redirecting to "Transfer to an Agent".

Is it possible to build in this way? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I can do it using a trigger on livechattranscript object.
You can look for the info in the chat conversation and create a case with these info.

Later, in the chat, the agent can see everything in this case

The user between ChatBot and SFDC is an integration user and you can’t “login” the customer who is using the chat

Comment: In order to write a trigger on livechattranscript, first I need to collect the Guest Details. For that I need to show a form where the Guest can enter his information. After that, I can create cases using triggers as you mentioned. But the problem here is, how do I show the form to the Guest before chatbot is transferring to an Agent.

Comment: When I make my Bot (Production Ready in a customer) I can show prechat, but was impossible to send the prechat info to Bot Flow/Agent. I dont know if it was a bug and now works.

Finally I decide to ask directly from Bot to customer all I need to save. And the trigger analyze and save all I need.

For me was very Helpful "Einstein Bot Cookbook for Beginners.pdf" but was so dificult to find in internet. If you want, send me your mail in a private message and I will send you the book

Comment: Yes, I have the cookbook for beginners.pdf and it's helpful. May be I need to find an alternate way to capture the user information from the bot. I will post here if I found any alternate way.

Answer (score 0):

After you setup the Einstein bot and the Embedded deployment and connect them together, inside the embedded deployment, you can disable the pre-chat form. This will make sure that when the chat starts, control transfers directly to the Einstein bot and when the bot has to redirect the chat to the agent, you can use the "Question" action inside the Einstein Bot to ask user information such as first name, last name, email etc and store the values inside variables. You might also need invocable apex classes to pass values from Einstein Bot variables to Chat transcript/case.